# Calculate and display Average Drawdown of strategy?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to add a dashboard on the chart showing below strategy performance statistics:

1. Average winning trade drawdown
2. Average losing trade drawdown

In simple terms, drawdown is the max percentage a trade moves in the opposite direction before closing.
In a long entry, if the prices reduces 2%, and then increase to 8% and trade is closed, then the drawdown would be 2%
If the price reduces to 2% and moves up by 1% only, then still the drawdown would be 2% (though the NP% would be - 1 %)
If the price reduces to 2% and closes there then the drawdown would be 2%, or the NP% loss would be drawdown.

How should i code this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strategy.closedtrades.max_drawdown(trade_num)` build in function to get the drawdown of a specific closed trade. This function will return the amount of the the drawdown, not the percentage.

You can use `strategy.closedtrades.entry_price(trade_num)` built in function to get the entry price of a specific closed trade, and use this in order to calculate the drawdown percentage. You can also use `for` loop to get all the closed trades. For example:

```
for i = 0 to strategy.closedtrades -1 
        // calculate the drawdown percentage
        drawdown = strategy.closedtrades.max_drawdown(i)
        costBasis = strategy.closedtrades.entry_price(i)
        drawdownPerc = drawdown / (costBasis * strategy.closedtrades.size(i))
```

After calculating, you'll need to store the results and get the average. I prefer to use arrays, but I guess there are multiple ways of doing that. To keep things clean, I wrote all of this in a function that returns a tuple of 2 elements - average winning trade drawdown and average losing trade drawdown:

```
avgDrawdown() =>
    
    // create new arrays to store the drawdown percent of each trade
    winArr = array.new_float()
    lossArr = array.new_float()
    
    for i = 0 to strategy.closedtrades -1 
        
        // calculate the drawdown percentage
        drawdown = strategy.closedtrades.max_drawdown(i)
        costBasis = strategy.closedtrades.entry_price(i)
        drawdownPerc = drawdown / (costBasis * strategy.closedtrades.size(i))
        
        // assign the result to the "win array" or "loss array" depending on the result of the trade (profit or loss)
        isWin = strategy.closedtrades.profit(i) >= 0
        
        if isWin
            array.push(winArr, drawdownPerc)
        else
            array.push(lossArr, drawdownPerc)
    
    // return a tuple of the average result of the two arrays
    [array.avg(winArr), array.avg(lossArr)]
```

Now all is left is calling the function when ever we need it, and display the results (or use it in any other way). For example, in order to display the results in a table:

```
t = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 1, rows = 2, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)

if barstate.islast
    // call the function and get the win and loss averages
    [win, loss] = avgDrawdown()
    
    // create the cells of the table
    table.cell(table_id = t, column = 0, row = 0, text = "Average winning trade drawdown " + str.tostring(win * 100, format.percent))
    table.cell(table_id = t, column = 0, row = 1, text = "Average losing trade drawdown " + str.tostring(loss * 100, format.percent))
```

Best of luck!!

**EDIT**

You can also split the trades to long and short in almost the same way. Just create 4 arrays instead of 2, and return a 4 element tuple instead of 2:

```
avgDrawdown() =>
    
    // create new arrays to store the drawdown percent of each trade
    longWinArr = array.new_float()
    longLossArr = array.new_float()
    shortWinArr = array.new_float()
    shortLossArr = array.new_float()
    
    for i = 0 to strategy.closedtrades -1 
        
        // calculate the drawdown percentage
        drawdown = strategy.closedtrades.max_drawdown(i)
        costBasis = strategy.closedtrades.entry_price(i)
        drawdownPerc = drawdown / (costBasis * strategy.closedtrades.size(i))
        
        // assign the result to the "long win array", "long loss array", "short win array" or "short loss array" depending on the result of the trade (profit or loss) and the position direction
        isWin = strategy.closedtrades.profit(i) >= 0
        isLong = strategy.opentrades.size(i) > 0
        
        
        if isLong
            if isWin
                array.push(longWinArr, drawdownPerc)
            else 
                array.push(longLossArr, drawdownPerc)
        else
            if isWin
                array.push(shortWinArr, drawdownPerc)
            else
                array.push(shortLossArr, drawdownPerc)

    
    // return a tuple of the average result of the four arrays
    [array.avg(longWinArr), array.avg(longLossArr), array.avg(shortWinArr), array.avg(shortLossArr)]
```

And then just call the function and show it in a table:

```
t = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 1, rows = 4, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)

if barstate.islast
    [longWin, longLoss, shortWin, shortLoss] = avgDrawdown()
    
    // create the cells of the table
    table.cell(table_id = t, column = 0, row = 0, text = "Average long winning trade drawdown " + str.tostring(longWin * 100, format.percent))
    table.cell(table_id = t, column = 0, row = 1, text = "Average long losing trade drawdown " + str.tostring(longLoss * 100, format.percent))
    table.cell(table_id = t, column = 0, row = 2, text = "Average short winning trade drawdown " + str.tostring(shortWin * 100, format.percent))
    table.cell(table_id = t, column = 0, row = 3, text = "Average short losing trade drawdown " + str.tostring(shortLoss * 100, format.percent))
```

Comment: Cant thank enough for the detailed answer.

Comment: I tried the below approach in my supertrend strategy (attached below). Then i tried to verify the figures by downloading the list of trades, and averaging the drawdown % of profitable trades and losing trades, but there was a big difference.
Is it possible for you to review what could go wrong? @mr_statler

Comment: **(https://snipboard.io/JkBmxc.jpg)**

I tried to add the function to display its result for a particular trade number to see if the values are correct.(Screenshot attached)
But the values are getting called incorrectly, or am i missing something?

Comment: Hi. There are few things to cover here. First, `strategy.closedtrades.max_drawdown(trade_num)` returns the amount of the drawdown, and not the percent. that means that the drawdown is 4.13 USDT in the example you attached. Second, `trade_num` parameter is zero based, while the numbers of the trades are not. That means that `strategy.closedtrades.max_drawdown(1400)` returns the drawdown in USDT of the 1401 trade (which is indeed 4.13 USDT). That is the reason why we calculated the drawdown percentage ourself. Same goes for the rest. Hope that clears things

Comment: Thanks alot. I was calculating the formula incorrectly. The actual formula for drawdown according to TV is "drawdown / costBasis * contracts".
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Do you think its possible to segregate Avg drawdown by long and short trades separately aswell? @mr_statler

Comment: Of course. See my edit (also fixed the issue you mentioned)

Comment: For the one last request. Its completely fine if you wish to ignore since ive taken alot more treasure then what i could i ask for.
--------------------------------
The final piece of the puzzle is i am trying to add drawdown analysis graph/chart or just a table even.
---------------------------------
1) 70% of Long Profit comes from trades having "Avg. Drawdown = xx
2) 20% of Long Profit comes from trades having "Avg. Drawdown = xx
3) 10% of Long Profit comes from trades having "Avg. Drawdown = xx
-------------------------------
and likewise for Long Loss, Short Profit, Short Loss.